# Error while create PDB database from another existing PDB in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I am struggling with an error when using **create pluggable database from** command. My config is:

**HOST_A - source CDB with couple of PDBs with ASM**

**HOST_B - destination CDB with couple of existing PDBs with ASM**

I would like to create a new pluggable database on HOST_B using dblink to HOST_A and "create pluggable database X from dbLink" statement, however I'm getting this error:

```
ORA-65169 Error encountered while attempting to copy file -- path to .DBF file on HOST_A 
ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server
ORA-19505: failed to identify file ""
```

I have checked above path to .dbf file and owner on HOST_A - it exists and has correct owner. Also, HOST_B has enough space to create new snapshot. What makes that even more weird, is that I have very similar HOST_C with same init parameters and it works without any problem. 
I noticed on HOST_B oracle has copied these files and placed them under valid ASM mount point with correct name etc, however create pluggable database still fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there  any other error in the alert log ?

Comment: Hmm interesting. There are some alerts "Failed to rename file +DATA/PATH/XXXYYYZZZ. I checked the path DATA/PATH/XXXYYYZZZ under /acfs mount point (ASM), but there's no such catalogue either on HOST_A and HOST_B. Why it's trying to rename something which non exists?